# Referencia Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

[**[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]**][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QzfB.png)Opa tudo bem? pra mim não to ficando maluco já kkkkk

Enfim, parece que quando eu crio um botão, ele não está sendo importado. Assim eu não tenho acesso para fazer um código. Alguém sabe como posso dar um jeito nesse panaca?

Answer (score 0):

**Rapaziada descobri o meu problema...**

*O que eu precisei fazer foi adicionar plugins ao Kotlin, mais especificamente esses aqui:*

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).